# How to use lambda functions or std::function with an API that takes function pointers?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Suppose I want to implement a simple abstraction over pthreads.
(or any C API that takes function pointers for callbacks or threads).

Like std::thread, I want the interface to be able to take function objects in general.

How do I bridge the gap in a way that works for all cases?
(That includes binds, lambda functions, etc.)

I know about the std::function::target but afaik, it does not do what I need.

Comment: Does the function pointer take argument (`void* userData`) ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I think hardcoding the argument types for a particular instance is acceptable. A template version would be better if possible, though.

Comment: Doesn't [`std::function::target()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) do what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

If the API takes functions with a `void*` for user data as, e.g., `pthread_create()` does, you'd pass a pointer to the function as user data, call a trampoline which casts the user data to your function type, and calls the function. For example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <pthread.h>

extern "C" void* trampoline(void* userData) {
    return (*static_cast<std::function<void*()>*>(userData))();
}

void* start() {
    // ...
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    std::function<void*()> entry(start);
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, &trampoline, &entry);
    // ...
}
```

The immediate implication is, however, that the function object life-time isn't easily controlled. In the example above the `std::function<void*()>` object happens to live long enough but it isn't always as easy.

If the function you try to call doesn't have a user data argument, you are pretty much out of luck. You might get away with using global objects but it is almost certainly a rather fragile approach.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function can be used anywhere that takes regular function pointers. In other words, it can be used wherever you would use regular functions/pointers to functions..

Example: https://ideone.com/4CJjlL

```
#include <iostream>

void voidfunc(void (*func_ptr)(void))
{
    func_ptr();
}

void funcwithargs(void (*func_ptr)(int, char, std::string), int a, char b, std::string c)
{
    func_ptr(a, b, c);
}

int main()
{
    auto vf = []{std::cout<<"Called void func..\n";};
    auto vfwa = [](int a, char b, std::string c) {std::cout<<"Called func with args with: "<<a<<b<<" "<<c<<"\n";};

    voidfunc(vf);
    funcwithargs(vfwa, 10, 'x', " + 3");
    return 0;
}
```

Likewise, you can use `std::function` instead of the function pointer..

Comment: Oh you're right, I did not notice that..  I guess you can't use `std::function` wherever there is a func ptr but you can use func ptr's or lambdas wherever there is an `std::function`.. I see now..